# jQuery FadeIn Pushes Content Out of Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a demo that shows button 2 appearing after 1 second of the page loading. However, the problem is that it moves the position of button 1 up, but I'd rather it not move at all.

I know this could be fixed by using position absolutes, not using space-between, etc, but I want to be able to fix this with the current CSS staying put.

How can this be fixed? I've tried to set the visibility from hidden to visible, but the problem with that is that it does not fade in nicely. Any ideas about the best tricks or tips to do this would be very helpful, thank you.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEWjNm

```js
setTimeout(() => $('#btn-2').fadeIn('slow'), 1000);
```

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#btn-2 { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id='btn-1'>button 1</button>
  <button id='btn-2'>button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. why not change the css
2. What's the expected behaviour, that button 2 fades in over button 1?

Comment: 1. because for better practice when I create similar effects in the future; 2. button 1 should keep its initial position but button 2 should just appear below after 1 second

Comment: Issue is due to flex column and aligning items center vertically , on adding new button it is adjusting accordingly

Comment: Can we change the html?

Comment: Actually sorry, yes - the CSS & HTML can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use animate option with opacity: 0 for btn2 initially

```js
setTimeout(() => $('#btn-2').animate({opacity:1}, 1000), 1000);
```

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#btn-2 { opacity: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id='btn-1'>button 1</button>
  <button id='btn-2'>button 2</button>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oVZrMK

Answer (score 1):

You can use container, then one div per button:

Where the container has styles:

```css
div.container {
      background: pink;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div>
      <button id='btn-1'>button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id='btn-2'>button 2</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that almost does it but you can see it changing slightly - i made a pen with your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaWKgK